# Meteor Cordova: How can I have portrait only orientation on iPhone and portrait and landscape on iPad

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am trying to setup my mobile-config.js file such that for the iphone it is portrait only and for the ipad it is allowed to go in portrait or landscape.

But I can't figure it out, and there is very little information on how to do this. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-info

The meteor docs specify how to lock the orientation according the the operating system like iOS vs Android, but now how to customize the orientation based on device.

How can I do this?

Comment: App.setPreference('Orientation', 'default'); show be portrait on iPhone/iPod and all orientations on iPad, if it doesn't work, then there is a bug. But you can't change it per devide (yet)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can customize orientation based on device type directly using meteor settings.

However, if you're building the app locally, you can manually edit the iOS .plist for the project and set the following keys:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

If you're building using a cloud service (or locally), you can set these preferences by adding configuration to your config.xml and including the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin in your project to apply it.
You'd add the following to your config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- Set orientation on iPhone -->
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>

    <!-- Set orientation on iPad -->
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>>
        </array>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```